# how can i extend a d3 interface in typescript?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

```
nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.name; });
```

in typescript, i get this error:

TS2551: Property '_children' does not exist on type 'HierarchyPointNode<{}>'. Did you mean 'children'?

how can i handle this error

this is my try:

```
import { HierarchyPointNode } from "d3";
declare interface HierarchyPointNode<Datum> {
   _children: any;
}
```

#### The flow is update:

The way i use d3 is import script file in the html

`<script src="../bower_components/d3/d3.min.js"></script>`

Then i run `npm install @types/d3`

In my global.d.ts file, I write this:

```
/// <reference types="d3" />
import { HierarchyPointNode } from 'd3';

declare module 'd3' {
    export interface HierarchyPointNode<Datum> {
        _children: any;
    }
}
```

But it can not help

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the interface in the same module as it comes from:

```
import { HierarchyPointNode } from 'd3';

declare module 'd3' {
    export interface HierarchyPointNode<Datum> {
        _children: any;
    }
}
```

Now, whevever you import this file directly (if you called it `d3-extensions.ts` you will have to import like this: `import "d3-extensions"`) you will be able to use the extended interface.

Hope this helps

Comment: it can not help, the detail, i supplement above;

Comment: What do you mean 'it cannot help'? Can you elaborate?

Comment: In my supplement of my question, i have add the code to my project, but  the error is still exist;